# Solo descargar imágenes cuando hay wifi usando Glide de Android

Tags: java, android, android-glide

¿Cómo hacer que las imágenes solo se pueda descargar si hay conexión wifi?

pero en caso de la imagen este disponible en la cache se muestre, es decir solo prevenir las nuevas descargas, mientras no este en conexión wifi.

#### Escenario posible

**Si hay red disponible WIFI**

```
imagen1 -> descargar -> cache -> visualización
imagen2 -> descargar -> cache -> visualización
imagen3
imagen4
```

**Sin conexión a WIFI**
Puede que el dispositivo este conectado a internet con los datos móviles, se debe prevenir las descarga para no consumir exceso de datos, pero si la imagen está en cache se visualice.

```
imagen1 -> cache -> visualización
imagen2 -> cache -> visualización
imagen3 -> mostrar imagen de error (no se ha descargado aun con wifi)
imagen4 -> mostrar imagen de error (no se ha descargado aun con wifi)
```

Lo que tengo

```
ImageView myImage = (ImageView) findViewById(R.id.image_view);

ConnectivityManager cm = (ConnectivityManager) this.getSystemService(Context.CONNECTIVITY_SERVICE);
NetworkInfo activeNetwork = cm.getActiveNetworkInfo();
if (activeNetwork != null)  isWifi = (activeNetwork.getType() == ConnectivityManager.TYPE_WIFI);

if (isWifi) {
    Log.i(TAG, "Wifi connected: ");
    Glide.with(this)
            .load("http://www.horadent.com/i/2017/05/nature-hd-wallpaper-high-quality.jpg")
            .diskCacheStrategy(DiskCacheStrategy.ALL)
            .error(R.drawable.ic_error_black_24dp)
            .into(myImage);

} else {
    //Cargar la imagen de la cache de GLIDE
}
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Prueba de esta manera; Se fuerza a Glide que trabaje sin red para que automáticamente cargue en cache:

Tu código:

```
ImageView myImage = (ImageView) findViewById(R.id.image_view);

 ConnectivityManager cm = (ConnectivityManager) this.getSystemService(Context.CONNECTIVITY_SERVICE);
 NetworkInfo activeNetwork = cm.getActiveNetworkInfo();
 if (activeNetwork != null)  isWifi = (activeNetwork.getType() == ConnectivityManager.TYPE_WIFI);

 if (isWifi) {
    Log.i(TAG, "Wifi connected: ");
    Glide.with(this)
            .load("http://www.horadent.com/i/2017/05/nature-hd-wallpaper-high-quality.jpg")
            .diskCacheStrategy(DiskCacheStrategy.ALL)
            .error(R.drawable.ic_error_black_24dp)
            .into(myImage);

} else {
    Log.i(TAG, "Wifi No connected: ");
    Glide.with(this)
            .using(new DesactivarInternetEnLoader())
            .load("http://www.horadent.com/i/2017/05/nature-hd-wallpaper-high-quality.jpg")
            .diskCacheStrategy(DiskCacheStrategy.ALL)
            .error(R.drawable.ic_error_black_24dp)
            .into(myImage);
}
```

Como ves, es el mismo código que arriba a excepción que pasándole un modelo. Por ultimo, la clase del modelo se vería asi:

```
class DesactivarInternetEnLoader implements StreamModelLoader<String> {
    @Override public DataFetcher<InputStream> getResourceFetcher(final String model, int width, int height) {
        return new DataFetcher<InputStream>() {
            @Override public InputStream loadData(Priority priority) throws Exception {
                throw new IOException("Glide Forzado");
            }
            @Override public String getId() { return model; }
            @Override public void cleanup() { }
            @Override public void cancel() { }
        };
    }
}
```